# iPhone Simulator is constantly crashing

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode12beta6

I'm running the latest macOS 11 beta (20A5364e) and Xcode 12b6 (20A5364e). When starting the Simulator it constantly crashes every 10-20s. Independent if an app is running or simply the Home Screen is shown. Anyone else/ Any known fixes?